# Backtracking Line Search Algorithm Implementation With Least Squares

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to implement the backtracking line search algorithm with Python to optimize a least squares function. The problem that I'm facing is that the error metric I'm receiving on each iteration is increasing rather than decreasing. The specific algorithm that I'm trying to implement is this:
[image: img].

The code I've written is as follows:

```
import numpy as np


# Least-square function
def f(x, A, b):
    return np.linalg.norm(A @ x - b) ** 2

# Gradient for least-square.
def grad(x, A, b):
    return 2 * (((A.T @ A) @ x) - A.T @ b)

# Parameters.
alpha = 0.3
beta = 0.8
t = 1
count = 1

A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5], [6]])
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, (2))
grad = grad(x, A, b)

# Algorithm implementation.
while (f((x - (t * grad)), A, b) > (f(x, A, b) - (alpha * t * np.linalg.norm(grad)**2))):
       t *= beta
       print('Iteration: {}'.format(count))
       error = f(x, A, b) - (f((x - (t * grad)), A, b) + (alpha * t) * np.linalg.norm(grad)**2)
       print('Error: {}'.format(error))
       count += 1
```

It runs fine, but when I check the output it looks something like this:

```
Iteration: 1
Error: -518474.8580281086
Iteration: 2
Error: -329567.4778574929
Iteration: 3
Error: -209120.46903309406
Iteration: 4
Error: -132397.3549733152
Iteration: 5
Error: -83584.93924532575
Iteration: 6
Error: -52577.294995627766
Iteration: 7
Error: -32918.244128793245
Iteration: 8
Error: -20485.124736396905
Iteration: 9
Error: -12646.866855165446
Iteration: 10
Error: -7725.532635099086
Iteration: 11
Error: -4651.999393394028
Iteration: 12
Error: -2745.8346460127177
Iteration: 13
Error: -1574.6064295366227
Iteration: 14
Error: -863.9941484702779
Iteration: 15
Error: -440.3813105705005
Iteration: 16
Error: -194.2123119007902
Iteration: 17
Error: -56.618726821093276
Iteration: 18
Error: 15.477508374778608
```

As far as I know, the error rate should *not* be increasing. I don't understand why this is the case, or perhaps my understanding of the algorithm is wrong and this is in fact normal?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry let me edit the question.

Comment: It is a function but the `while` loop should be receiving a value. I added the line `grad = grad(x, A, b)` to fix the error.

Comment: It's basically matrix multiplication. https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#short-answer

Comment: isn't the idea to get `0` error? If so your optimization is working.

Comment: where is t/2? in given fig there is t / 2 but not seen in code.

Comment: @DrBwts My initial thought would be that the smaller the error the better. I'm not sure if it should be 0 or not.

Comment: @JainilPatel I took out the (1/2) because it's a scalar value that doesn't affect the overall output.

Comment: the closer the absolute value of your error is to `0` the better. That is you want the error to converge onto `0` regaurdless of which direction its comming from

Comment: Yes but my problem uses neither the MSE or MAE. Does that concept still apply?